# what word means you feel badly about something for one reason but equally as good for another reason?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example: a close friend died of cancer, so you feel very bad. Yet they were old and no longer suffering, so you also feel glad. Both feelings are strong and truthful, yet the emotions about the same object or situation equally oppose each other.

Ambivalent comes close, but I was looking for another word to more exactly describe the situation. Ambivalent would describe a struggle where you might not like something about someone, yet still like other characteristics, hence you are uncertain how to balance the situation (be their friend or walk away). What word describes when you are not struggling to balance two truths, but accept both opposing feelings?  I ask because we are helping someone who is grieving.

Comment: I deleted the "word-choice" tag, since you weren't asking us to choose from a given selection, and replaced it with the SWR tag, which applies to questions like this one. Please note that [it asks you to provide a sample sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), because doing so is very helpful for people trying to answer such questions.

Comment: I don't think the suggested answers for the 'duplicate' exactly fit this situation. The most likely expression is _I feel mixed emotions_.